# What can I do to make this Perlin noise generator more efficient?

Tags: python, perlin-noise

```
from PIL import Image
import math
import numpy
import random

random.seed(10)

a = 2000

br = 200

grad = []

for i in range(int(a/br)+1):
    row = []
    for j in range(int(a/br)+1):
            row.append([random.randint(-1,1),random.randint(-1,1)])
    grad.append(row)

def wt(a,b,w):
    
    return (b - a) * ((w * (w * 6.0 - 15.0) + 10.0) * w * w * w) + a

    #return (b - a) * w + a

    #return (b - a) * (3.0 - w * 2.0) * w * w + a

def graddotproduct(x,y,dx,dy):

    return( ( grad[y][x][0] * dx) + (grad[y][x][1] * dy) )

def perlin(x,y,numpix):

    x0 = int(math.floor(x))
    x1 = x0 + 1
    y0 = int(math.floor(y))
    y1 = y0 + 1

    sx0 = x - x0
    sx1 = x - x1
    sy0 = y - y0
    sy1 = y - y1

    d1 = [sx0,sy0]
    d2 = [sx1,sy0]
    d3 = [sx0,sy1]
    d4 = [sx1,sy1]

    dot1 = graddotproduct(x0,y0,sx0,sy0)
    dot2 = graddotproduct(x1,y0,sx1,sy0)
    dot3 = graddotproduct(x0,y1,sx0,sy1)
    dot4 = graddotproduct(x1,y1,sx1,sy1)

    ix0 = wt(dot1,dot2,sx0)
    ix1 = wt(dot3,dot4,sx0)

    avrg = wt(ix0,ix1,sy0)
    
    return avrg

img = Image.new( 'RGB', (a,a), "black")
pixels = img.load()

for x in range(a):
    for y in range(a):
        perll = perlin(x/br,y/br,a)
        pixels[x,y] = (int((perll+1)*128),int((perll+1)*128),int((perll+1)*128))

img.show()
img.save("vector.png")
```

I made this by following a Wiki article about Perlin noise that implemented it in C. The creator of the wiki article implemented their own random number generation, but I didn't understand it well enough to replicate it in Python, so I resorted to using Python's 'Random' module.

The Wiki article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise

The code usually takes around 10-15 seconds to produce the image. Which is quite slow compared to noise generators used by other applications such as Blender or Unity.

Comment: Consider using threads to parallelize the y loop

Comment: And instead of changing the pixels of an image work with numpy matrices to do all calculations. Once you get your matrix filles with values transform it to an image at once.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using list comprehension, rather than building list by multiple appends, for example

```
row = []
for j in range(int(a/br)+1):
        row.append([random.randint(-1,1),random.randint(-1,1)])
```

is equivalent to

```
row = [[random.randint(-1,1),random.randint(-1,1)] for j in range(int(a/br)+1)]
```